# How to set NavigationView's headerView with Anko DSL?

Tags: android, kotlin, dsl, anko

In general XML layout, the default main layout is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried to code this with Anko DSL:

```
...

override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {
    drawerLayout {
        lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)
        id = ID_DRAWER_LAYOUT
        fitsSystemWindows = true

        navigationView {
            lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent)
            id = ID_NAVIGATION_VIEW
            foregroundGravity = Gravity.START
            fitsSystemWindows = true

            addHeaderView(navHeaderView()) //// PROBLEM HERE ////
            inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer)
        }
    }
}

private fun ViewGroup.navHeaderView() {
    linearLayout {
        lparams(width = matchParent, height = dip(160))
        backgroundResource = R.drawable.side_nav_bar
        gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
        orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        setPadding(dip(64), dip(16), dip(64), dip(16))

        imageView {
            id = ID_IMAGE_VIEW
            topPadding = dip(16)
            imageResource = android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon
        }

        textView {
            lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
            id = ID_TEXT_NAME
            topPadding = dip(16)
            text = "test1"
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                setTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Body1)
            } else {
                setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)
            }
        }

        textView {
            id = ID_TEXT_DESCRIPTION
            text = "test2"
        }
    }
}

...
```

The marked line throws an exception saying that the view has already had a parent.

---

Then I tried to use the Anko DSL Preview plugin to convert the xml automatically, it just did it like this, not completely changed it into Anko DSL:

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout {
    id = Ids.drawer_layout

    include<View>(R.layout.app_bar_main).lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)
    org.mewx.projectprpr.template.NavigationFitSystemView {
        id = Ids.nav_view
        app:headerLayout = @layout/nav_header_main //// HERE ////
        app:menu = @menu/activity_main_drawer
    }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent)
}
```

How can I add the header view with Anko DSL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, DrawerLayout in its constructor checks `fistSystemWindows` and sets status bar background, so, unfortunately, the easiest way to use DrawerLayout with `fitsSystemWindows` is inflating it from XML.

Second, Anko DSL methods not just create new views, but attach them to parent as well. You must create a detached view:

```
addHeaderView(UI {
    navHeaderView()
}.view)
```

This code is intended to use with Anko `0.10.0-beta-2`, behavior and even syntax may vary from version to version.

Third, I've caught a bug: when I open drawer while keyboard is shown, header view gets large bottom padding (inset). My sad workaround looks like this:

```
addHeaderView(
  object : _RelativeLayout(context) { // fixes bottomPadding with open keyboard :'(
    @TargetApi(20) override fun onApplyWindowInsets(insets: WindowInsets) =
        insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
  }.apply {
    /* DSL code here */
  })
```